# Writing results of NLTK FreqDist to a .csv file as a row in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, nltk, export-to-csv

I'm attempting to write out the results of a frequency count of specific words in a text file based on a collection of words in a python list ( I haven't included it in the code listing as there are several hundred)

```
file_path = 'D:/TestHedges/Hedges_Test_11.csv'
corpus_root = test_path
wordlists = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*')
print(wordlists.fileids())
CIK_List = []
freq_out = []

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(test_path, '*.txt')):

 CIK = filename[33:39]
 CIK = CIK.strip('_')
 # CIK = CIK.strip('_0') commented out to see if it deals with just removing _.  It does not 13/9/2020



 newstext = wordlists.words()
 fdist = nltk.FreqDist([w.lower() for w in newstext])

 CIK_List.append(CIK)
 with open(file_path, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
  writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
  writer.writerow(["CIK"] + word_list)
  for val in CIK_List:
   writer.writerow([val])
  for m in word_list:
     print(CIK, [fdist[m]], end='')
     writer.writerows([fdist[m]])
```

My problem is with the writing of `fdist[m]` as a row into a .csv file.  It is generating an error

```
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not int
```

How can I re-write this to place the frequency distribution into a row in a .csv file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices - either use `writerow` instead of `writerows` or create a list of values first and then pass it to `writer.writerows` instead of `fdist[m]`. Now, each of the row values in the list should be a tuple (or an interable). Therefore, for `writerows` to work you would have to encapsulate it again in a tuple:

```
 writer.writerows([(fdist[m],)])
```

Here, the comma denotes a 1-value tuple.

In order to write all of the values in one row instead of this code:

```
for m in word_list:
     print(CIK, [fdist[m]], end='')
     writer.writerows([fdist[m]])
```

You should use:

```
for m in word_list:
     print(CIK, [fdist[m]], end='')
writer.writerows(([fdist[m] for m in word_list],))
```

### Please note a list comprehension.

On a different note, just by looking at your code, it seems to me that you could do the same without involving `NLTK` library just by using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from standard library. It is the underlying container in `FreqDist` class.

Comment: It is writing the correct values out, but on separate lines (in a column).  What I need is to write the counts in one row but separate cells in a .csv file.  I'm using NLTK to do this as we'll be making more use of it later for TF-IDF calculations.  Also, this code will build a corpus of text files where I actually need it to count the number of words occurring in each text file in a directory.

Comment: I'm concatenating the CIK number with the FreqDist to the file like this  ```  for val in CIK_List:
   writer.writerows(([val] + [f_dist[m] for m in word_list],))```  but it's only writing out the frequency distribution for the last file in the directory.  Is this an indentation issue with python or is there some other reason?